# Angular test formGroupDirective get function on init

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to test a multistep form that I've created. For each step I'm passing in a form group name then calling FormGroupDirective.control.get in ngOnInit to get the formGroup used in that particular component.

Here's my step-one component setup.

```
export class StepOneComponent implements OnInit {
  stepForm!: FormGroup;
  billingRequired = false;

  @Input() formGroupName!: string;
  @Input() formHeading: string;

  constructor(private rootFormGroup: FormGroupDirective, private formService: FormService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stepForm = this.rootFormGroup.control.get(this.formGroupName) as FormGroup;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.formService.billingToggle();
  }
}
```

And the form initialized in my formService

```
multiStepForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    orgInformation: this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      address: ['', [Validators.required]],
      country: ['', [Validators.required]],
      city: ['', [Validators.required]],
      state: ['', [Validators.required]],
      zip: ['', [Validators.required]],
      contactFirstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      contactMiddleName: [''],
      contactLastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      contactSuffix: [''],
      contactEmail: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      contactPhone: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]],
      contactExt: [''],
    }),
    billingInformation: this.fb.group({
      cardNumber: ['', [Validators.required]],
      expiration: ['', [Validators.required]],
      cvv: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
      cardName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    })
  })
```

For the test I am trying to just get the basic setup figured out. Despite setting up a mock formGroup for stepForm, I keep getting `NG01052: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.`

Here's my test so far

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { StepOneComponent } from './step-one.component';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormGroupDirective, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormService } from 'src/app/services/form/formservice.service';

describe('StepOneComponent', () => {
  let component: StepOneComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<StepOneComponent>;
  let service: FormService;
  const formgroupstub = {
    control: {
        get: jasmine.createSpy('get')
    }
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [StepOneComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: FormGroupDirective, useValue: formgroupstub },
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StepOneComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    service = TestBed.inject(FormService);

    component.formGroupName = 'orgInformation';
    component.stepForm = new FormGroup({
      orgInformation: new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      }),
    });

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I'm trying to mock the formGroupDirective properly so I can test this component, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely need to add `ReactiveFormsModule` to the `imports` array.

```
imports: [
  StepOneComponent,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
],
```

But that's most likely not the main issue.

The main issue is that we are mocking `stepForm` for it to be overridden in the `ngOnInit`. The first `fixture.detectChanges` is when `ngOnInit` is called.

So we assign a correct value to `stepForm` only for it to be overridden in the `fixture.detectChanges()` call where `ngOnInit` is called and assigns it to the mock service's value. The mock service value is returning `undefined` at the moment.

To potentially fix it, we could try something like:

```
component.formGroupName = 'orgInformation';
// Make the get of the stub return the form value for it to be populated
// in the ngOnInit.
formgroupstub.control.get.and.returnValue(new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      }),
    }));
// Now call fixture.detectChanges() which will call ngOnInit
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation and the answer! Making the stub return the form controls fixed the issue, although I had to make it return ALL the controls in that formgroup.